# How can I apply regular expression to filter a string

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

How can I apply regular expression to filter only

```
[video src="http://duel.evotechaustin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/kramer.m4v" width="480" height="360" id="b-test" class="player" ]
```

from the following string

```
Is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
[video src="http://duel.evotechaustin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/kramer.m4v"          width="480" height="360" id="b-test" class="player" ]
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
```

or Without using regular expression and Dom is there anyways to get the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/\[video[^\]]+\]/i", $subject, $matches);
```

`$matches[0]` contains

```
[video src="http://duel.evotechaustin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/kramer.m4v" width="480" height="360" id="b-test" class="player"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a shortcode and you can easily use the [WordPress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to handle those shortcodes:

```
function video_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  // do whatever you want to to
}
add_shortcode('video', 'video_shortcode');
```

In the `$atts` array you will have a list of all of your attributes from the video shortcode:

```
array(
    "src" => "http://duel.evotechaustin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/kramer.m4v",
    "width" => "480",
    "height" => "360",
    "id" => "b-test",
    "class" => "player"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substring and indexOf

for example,

```
htmlString = document.getElementById('div').innerHtml();
startIndex = htmlString.indexOf("[video");
endIndex = htmlString.indexOf("]", startIndex);
output = htmlString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Comment: Should be difficult to use JavaScript in PHP :)